# Relation defined on the set of real numbers by xRy when $x^2 + y^2 = 1$. Show whether or not R is reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric or transitive.

Tags: proof-verification, relations, real-numbers, equivalence-relations

> Let R be the relation defined on the set of real numbers by $xRy$
>   whenever $x^2 + y^2 = 1.$ Show whether or not $R$ is reflexive,
>   symmetric, antisymmetric or transitive.

All right so I think I've got this right and just want to make sure.

- Symmetric - Yes for all $x$ and $y$, if  $x^2 + y^2 = 1$  then  $1 = x^2 + y^2 $
- Reflexive - Yes for all $x$ and $y$, if  $x^2 + y^2 = x^2 +y^2$
- Anti-Symmetric - Yes for all $x$ and $y$, if  $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $1 = x^2 + y^2$ then $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ is true.
- Transitive - Yes, if $x^2 + y^2 = x_2^2 + y_2^2 $ and $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ then  $x_2^2 + y_2^2 =1$

I think I've done all these right, unless I've misunderstood the definitions for the relations.

Comment: Antisymmetric would mean if $xRy$ and $x\ne y$ then $y\not Rx$

Comment: You seem to be confusing the role of the variables with the role of the equals sign. For example, for symmetry, the point isn't to switch the left-hand side with the right-hand side, but rather to replace all $x$ with $y$ and all $y$ with $x$.

Comment: Is this result true for any radius? If $x^2+y^2=r^2$ then this relation is also reflexive, but transitive does not hold. Please guide me about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstood. Instead of using the $R$ notation, say that $x \sim y$ if and only if $x^2+y^2=1$. So

- Not reflexive, as we have elements $x$ such that $x \not\sim x$. For example, $1 \not\sim 1$, as $1^2+1^2 = 2 \neq 1$.
- It is symmetric, because if $x \sim y$, then $x^2+y^2 = 1$. So $y^2+x^2=1$ says that $y \sim x$.
- Not transitive for reasons similar to reflexivity. For example, $1 \sim 0$ and $0 \sim 1$, but $1 \not\sim 1$.

And so on...

Comment: Alright so if I'm understanding this for anti-symmetric fails because if  $1^2 + 0^2$ holds true and   $0^2 + 1^2$  holds true, then 0 = 1, but it doesn't. So anti-symmetric is false

Comment: The sentence "$1^2 + 0^2$ holds true" makes no sense. Of course you meant "$1^2+0^2 = 1$ holds true", but at this stage of learning proofs one should be careful with these things. Your logic for concluding that anti-symmetry breaks down is correct, but you can phrase it is a less clumsy way, e.g. "$1 \sim 0$ (because $1^2+0^2=1$) and $0 \sim 1$ (because $0^2+1^2 =1$), but $0 \neq 1$" (I mean, don't introduce unnecessary contradictions in your reasoning).

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately your answer is mostly wrong. For example; that $R$ is reflexive means that $xRx$ holds for all real numbers $x$. But clearly $x^2+x^2=1$ does *not* hold for all real numbers $x$, so the relation is *not* reflexive.

Transitivity and antisymmetry also fail, and symmetry *does* hold though you may want to verify this again with a proper understanding of what the relation is.